# How to add a derived column to a dataframe using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a data frame with columns

- `patient_id`,
- `DOB`,
- `Gender`,
- `marital_status`,
- `smoking_status`,
- `city`

I need to extract age from the column `DOB` and add a new column `age` to my data frame. How can I proceed using Scala?

Comment: please provide sample input data, expected output dataframe and your tried code.

Comment: Yes and add the output of printSchema, just to know if it's a string, a java.sql.Date or a timestamp, thx

Comment: Maybe this can help you : [Link about UDF solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484068/convert-date-of-birth-into-age-in-spark-dataframe-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val df = sqlcontext.sql(" SELECT *, DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,"+GETDATE()+")/8766 AS AgeYearsIntTrunc")
```

Comment: Why it is divided by 8766? Can you please explain?

Comment: It assumes 8766 hours per year, which works out to 365.25 days. Since there are no years with 365.25 days(.25 is because of leap year), this will be incorrect near the person's birth date more often than it is correct. if needed accurately then refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57599/how-to-calculate-age-in-t-sql-with-years-months-and-days)

Comment: when I run this query i am getting an error: not found:value GETDATE