# Convert Date Column to Age with Scala and Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a Column of a Dataset to true Age. 
I am using Scala with Spark and my project is on IntelliJ.

This is the sample dataset

```
TotalCost|BirthDate|Gender|TotalChildren|ProductCategoryName
1000||Male|2|Technology
2000|1957-03-06||3|Beauty
3000|1959-03-06|Male||Car
4000|1953-03-06|Male|2|
5000|1957-03-06|Female|3|Beauty
6000|1959-03-06|Male|4|Car
7000|1957-03-06|Female|3|Beauty
8000|1959-03-06|Male|4|Car
```

And this is the code of Scala

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataFrameFromCSVFile2 {

def main(args:Array[String]):Unit= {

val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local[1]")
  .appName("SparkByExample")
  .getOrCreate()

val filePath="src/main/resources/demodata.txt"

val df = spark.read.options(Map("inferSchema"->"true","delimiter"->"|","header"->"true")).csv(filePath).select("Gender", "BirthDate", "TotalCost", "TotalChildren", "ProductCategoryName")

val df2 = df
  .filter("Gender is not null")
  .filter("BirthDate is not null")
  .filter("TotalChildren is not null")
  .filter("ProductCategoryName is not null")
df2.show()
```

So I am trying to convert the 1957-03-06 to an age like 61 in the Column

Any idea will help a lot

Thank you very much

Comment: Similar question already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484068/convert-date-of-birth-into-age-in-spark-dataframe-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way that uses the `java.time` API in an UDF along with Spark's built-in `when/otherwise` for null check:

```
val currentAge = udf{ (dob: java.sql.Date) =>
  import java.time.{LocalDate, Period}
  Period.between(dob.toLocalDate, LocalDate.now).getYears
}

df.withColumn("CurrentAge", when($"BirthDate".isNotNull, currentAge($"BirthDate"))).
  show(5)
// +------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
// |Gender|          BirthDate|TotalCost|TotalChildren|ProductCategoryName|CurrentAge|
// +------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
// |  Male|               null|     1000|            2|         Technology|      null|
// |  null|1957-03-06 00:00:00|     2000|            3|             Beauty|        61|
// |  Male|1959-03-06 00:00:00|     3000|         null|                Car|        59|
// |  Male|1953-03-06 00:00:00|     4000|            2|               null|        65|
// |Female|1957-03-06 00:00:00|     5000|            3|             Beauty|        61|
// +------+-------------------+---------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built-in functions - months_between() or datediff(). Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq("1957-03-06","1959-03-06").toDF("date")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [date: string]

scala> df.show(false)
+----------+
|date      |
+----------+
|1957-03-06|
|1959-03-06|
+----------+

scala> df.withColumn("age",months_between(current_date,'date)/12).show
+----------+------------------+
|      date|               age|
+----------+------------------+
|1957-03-06|61.806451612500005|
|1959-03-06|59.806451612500005|
+----------+------------------+

scala> df.withColumn("age",datediff(current_date,'date)/365).show
+----------+-----------------+
|      date|              age|
+----------+-----------------+
|1957-03-06|61.85205479452055|
|1959-03-06|59.85205479452055|
+----------+-----------------+


scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Calendar library to get the current date in your timezone to calculate the age. you can use udf to do that.
for example

```
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.util.Calendar

val data = Seq("1957-03-06","1959-03-06").toDF("date")

val ageudf = udf((inputDate:String)=>{

val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
val birthDate = format.parse(inputDate).toInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate
val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime..toInstant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate
import java.time.Period
if((birthDate != null) && (currentDate != null)) Period.between(birthDate,currentDate).getYears
else 0
})

data.withColumn("age",ageUdf($"date")).show()
```

The output will be:

```
date|age
1957-03-06|61
1959-03-06|59
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.